# Is it possible to set default log file for an entire python project?

Tags: python, django

I'm using the django-mailer library which, in [engine.py](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer/blob/58c728c6b7153a9417c482ab76c281442a4fd06e/mailer/engine.py) includes logging calls:

```
...
if connection is None:
    connection = get_connection(backend=EMAIL_BACKEND)
logging.info("sending message '{0}' to {1}".format(
    message.subject.encode("utf-8"),
    u", ".join(message.to_addresses).encode("utf-8"))
)
...
```

However the code does not set up a destination for this logging. I'd like to set this up without making any modifications to the library code.

So where would I put in configuration that selects the file to use? In the case of Django, would putting something in the settings.py file work? Is that recommended/not recommended?

I have read through the [Python documentation on logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) but it's not clear how you would set it up from a different file so that it works globally.

Also, anyway to limit logging from a specific library? So instead of having all logging going to a central file, I could have it go to a file just for django-mailer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up logging pretty flexibly in the settings file.  Plenty of documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/).

Answer (score 0):

Just an example to go along with the logging docs that @seddonym pointed you to (Django docs will be more helpful than Python docs in this case). In your Django settings.py file, you could include a logging config like:

```
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'custom': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': <path_to_your_log_file>,
            'mode': 'a',
            'maxBytes': 10000000,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['custom'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```